# shadowgrounds/trine humble bundle does not work

Tags: 12.04, installation, games

I had a notebook with 1.6 atom processor and 2 gig ram that ran all the programs/games from the trine/shadowgrounds humble bundle without much of a problem. I now have a laptop with a 2.5 dual core and 8 gig ram (both have/had integrated graphics cards) and I now cannot get these games to work. I see many posts about how they will not work with integrated graphics cards but considering not long ago i was running them on a crap notebook, i have a hard time understanding that. the games will flash open and slam shut as soon as i try to execute them, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As Joel said below, attempt to find the exact graphics card, you probably are missing a driver. If you have the open source one with the kernel you might have some serious issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try to find out the exact graphics cards in both computers - there's a variety of integrated cards out there and they're not all the same. The old notebook may have had a good ATi/NVIDIA integrated one, whereas the new could be stuck with an old Intel (a bit unlikely though). You can check the FAQ at http://frozenbyte.com/help_humble/linuxfaq.html

If nothing helps feel free to get in touch at http://www.frozenbyte.com/contact/

- Joel, Frozenbyte team